# Angular - How to trigger a child scope's resize event in code, from the parent scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, resize, jquery-events

I am working on a web-app project, using Angular for the front-end. One of the views (View A) is divided into 3 full-width sections - header, main, footer.

- Header is always fixed-height.
- Main is occupied at all times by one of 2 partial views/child scopes (A1, A2). The user can select which is visible using a toggle button on the header, and visibility is controlled using ng-show.
- Footer is variable-height, and can be resized by the user.

The child view inside the Main section needs to be resized based on the size of the footer. Therefore in each of the child scopes, a function `onSize` is bound to the footer's resize event (using JQuery) to handle resizing.

The problem is that when using the toggle button to switch between A1 and A2, the newly shown child scope has the wrong size, because it had not been receiving the footer's `resize` event while hidden. My question is, how can I programmatically trigger the child's resize event when the toggle button is pressed?

Comment: Without enough code to reproduce this it is very hard for anyone to help. Provide relevant resize code and basic html structure in question. Creating a demo also that reproduces this issue would be a big help to getting solutions also

Comment: Also think that your whole issue might be resolved using `flex-box` css without script needed